# Go build shared-c is not outputting a header file

Tags: go

I am trying to test build a shared C lib in GoLang, and the output does not create a header file (.h)

test.go:

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

func ExportedFun(s string) {
    fmt.Printf("C gave us %s string", s)
}

func main() {}
```

and the command I run is:

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o test.so test.go
```

I get the `.so` file but no header file.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [go command documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_build_modes):

> The only callable symbols will be those functions exported using a cgo
>   //export comment.

Th syntax for exporting a function via cgo can be found in the [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go)

> Go functions can be exported for use by C code in the following way:
>
> ```
> //export MyFunction
> func MyFunction(arg1, arg2 int, arg3 string) int64 {...}
>
> //export MyFunction2
> func MyFunction2(arg1, arg2 int, arg3 string) (int64, *C.char) {...}
> ```

Marking your function as exported will generate the header.

Comment: Ha ha... Something so simple (facepalm)... Thank you

Comment: I don't get it. The point is the first uppercase letter right? I've got `func TestFunc() { some code }` and building with `go build -o test.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go`. Still there is only the `.so` file.

Comment: @C4u you saved my day

Comment: It's also quite fussy - the lack of space between `//` and `export` is important.

Comment: Also import "C" is needed otherwise it wouldn't generate header.

Comment: nice catch, I indented my export and was surprised why it was not generating the header file

Comment: @ShivendraMishra thanks for this. I had everything else correct, but I had import "C" missing. Great tip.